# Nuget update on build

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I'm having difficulties getting my project to update our in-house nuget packages on a rebuild. We have several core reference libraries that we need to be current every time a project that depends on it is built.

I'm using visual studio 2017 and nuget 4.7.1

I've converted the project in question to use the package reference method instead of package.config but the details it's generating in the project file are different to what the tutorials say.

Here's what I've got in my project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="SMSCore">
  <Version>10.5.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="STMICore">
  <Version>10.5.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

The nuget documentation says this though:

```
<!-- Accepts any 6.x.y version. -->
<PackageReference Include="ExamplePackage" Version="6.*" />
<PackageReference Include="ExamplePackage" Version="[6,7)" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning

I've tried altering my project file to look like the reference material.
I've tried just using the versioning methods in the format the project file started in.

Nothing really seems to be working.
Maybe I'm looking at the wrong documentation?
I'm pretty new to defining and using nuget repositories so I wouldn't be surprised if it's something simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: do you have a project file that your issue replicates with and we can actually try out? does the `6.*` work? having `Version` as element or attribute is the same for msbuild, the attribute is just a syntax improvement.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't matter if I move the version from being a sub-element to an attribute of the parent (like in the example) it still works.  
  
I guess what I need to know is if it's possible to have the project update all its dependent nuget packages when the project is built? If it is, how?  
  
I tried putting together an empty windows form application and threw my core packages into it and they behaved the same way.
When I use the "[10,6)" method it won't even let me open the nuget package manager anymore.

Comment: @DrBoon, Is there any reason to use the `Packagereference` instead of `package.config`? If using `package.config`, it will be very easy.

Comment: None at all. I've actually just switched my project back to package.config to try and get it working that way. 
I think I've been a bit mislead by the documentation because there's so much crap espousing how wonderful package reference is.

Comment: @DrBoon, Packagereference is still a relatively new product and works primarily with new project type SDK. If it works with a non-sdk project, there will be some additional issues. I will give a detailed explanation later.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT thank you. I thought this might be the case. Thank you for that. I really wasn't clear on which direction to go.

Comment: @DrBoon, I have posted answer for this issue and updated it. If you are have any unclear, please let me know for free. Generally speaking, if your project type is SDK, we suggest to use `PackageReference`, if your project type is non-SDK, we suggest to use `package.config`, But this is not completely absolute. https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess what I need to know is if it's possible to have the project update all its dependent nuget packages when the project is built?

If you are using the `package.config`, it will be very easy to update all its dependent nuget packages. We just need add a pre-build event to update it:

```
<YourNuGetCLIPath>\nuget.exe update "YourSolutionFile.sln or PackageId"
```

Check [update command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-update) for some more details.

If you are using `PackageReference`, it will become a bit more complicated. That because [`NuGet.exe` update does not support `PackageReference`](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6115). In this case, we have to use floating versions to automatically update packages (You mentioned in the question), but it not work for all its dependent nuget packages, so floating versions does not seem to suit you either. what's more, if you are using `PackageReference`, there is another issue on the NuGet Package Manage UI:

[NuGet Build Integrated Project handling of floating versions and ranges in Visual Studio Client](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-NuGet-Build-Integrated-Project-handling-of-floating-versions-and-ranges-in-Visual-Studio-Client)

Besides, if your project type is SDK `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`, there is another workaround to update all its dependent nuget packages with `PackageReference`, you can use `dotnet add` to change the version of the `PackageReference` in the pre-build event:

```
dotnet add "$(ProjectPath)" package PackageID
```

If you are using `non-SDK` + `PackageReference`, I have not found any valid workarounds yet.

So, if there is no restriction on using `package.config`, I think `package.config` is best for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I had read in several places that using update in a pre-build step was too late as far as nuget is concerned. But I'll give it a shot and see what happens :)

Comment: Do I need to define a version range in the packages.config? Or will the update command ignore that?

Comment: @DrBoon, No, no need to define a version range in the packages.config. Update  command will update the package to the latest version.

Comment: Ok, I'm really struggling to get the syntax right on the pre-build. In the build events tab of the project properties I'm trying to put this as a pre-build event: C:\Program Files(x86)\Nuget\Nuget.exe update <solution name>
But it's not working. Clearly I'm doing something wrong and it must be pretty simple because I can't google an answer :/

Comment: Nevermind. Nothing wrong with syntax. Nuget is executing several folders too deep within the solution. I need to bring it back up...